# Confused about a proposition about rational polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

I'm studing complex analysis.I saw that

> $R(z)$ is a rational function.Consider the function  $R(1/z)$ which we can rewrite as a rational function $R_1(z)$,and set $R(\infty)=R_1(0).$
>
> with the notation $$R(z)=\frac{a_0+a_1z+\ldots+a_nz^n}{b_0+b_1z+\ldots+b_mz^m}$$
>
> we obtain $$R_1(z)=\frac{a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n}{b_0z^m+b_1z^{m-1}+\ldots+b_m}z^{m-n}$$

After "we obtain" I am not sure what is happening .
Could anyone show more detail about it?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See what happens when you substitute in for $R(1/z)$. Given the definition of $R$, this will give us:

$$R(1/z)=\frac{a_0+a_1z^{-1}+\ldots+a_nz^{-n}}{b_0+b_1z^{-1}+\ldots+b_mz^{-m}}$$

We can rewrite the powers of $z$ in the numerator and denominator as follows. Note that all I have done here is re-express the exponents of $z$: $0 = n-n$, $-1 = (n-1) -n$, etc.

$$R(1/z)=\frac{a_0 z^{n-n} + a_1 z^{(n-1)-n} + \ldots + a_n z^{0-n}}{b_0 z^{m-m} +b_1 z^{(m-1)-m} + \ldots + b_m z^{0-m}}$$

And hence, we can pull some factors of $z$ out of the fraction:

$$R(1/z)=\frac{a_0 z^n + a_1 z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_n z^{0}}{b_0 z^{m} +b_1 z^{m-1} + \ldots + b_m z^{0}} \cdot \frac{z^{-n}}{z^{-m}}$$

Rewriting the fraction on the right as a simple power of $z$, we get:

$$z^{-n}/z^{-m} = z^m/z^n = z^{m-n}$$

Letting $R_1(z)$ be *defined* as $R(1/z)$, we finally get the result that "[they] obtain":

$$R_1(z) := R(1/z)=\frac{a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n}{b_0z^m+b_1z^{m-1}+\ldots+b_m}z^{m-n}$$